# How to exponentiate matrix columns with a vector in Python from original in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix

I am translating a code from MATLAB into Python using numpy. However, I have encountered an exponentiation that gives me a

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (40,40) into shape (40)
```

Here is a reproducible problem

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(1240).reshape(40, 31)
b = np.ones(a.shape)
c = np.ones((40, 1))
```

The calculation I want:

```
for n in range(31):
    b[:, n] = a[:, n] ** c
```

The original MATLAB code

```
for n=1:1:N
cp(:,n) = c(:,n).^(T);
end
```

T is a 40, 1 matrix, cp and c are a 31, 40 matrix

Also, if there is any Pythonic way do to this, let me know.

Comment: to get the power operation you have 31 bases but 40 powers. That's what it is complaining about. Maybe you meant to have the shape 40, 31 ?

Comment: I get the same error. And in the actual program I get the shapes as they are. This is just to reproduce my actual cp

Comment: Try: `a = np.arange(1240).reshape(40, 31)`
`c = np.ones((40, 1))` `b = a**c`. No loop required.

Comment: The MATALB code with a loop isn't very `matlab-onic`, at least not in the versions that I used years ago.  Loops like that were slow.  Newer versions do some sort of `jit` compiling that reduces the penalty of looping.  On the other hand, `numpy` had broadcasting long before either Octave or MATLAB.